# Como enviar um nome de um formulário html para outro arquivo html? E fiz usando php. Mas a faculdade quer dois arquivos html. Dá pra fazer isso?

Tags: php, html, post

Codigo da pagina 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tela de Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 50px; font-family: arial black; ">Tela de Login</p>
        <div class="row align-itens-center">
            <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto col-lg-5">
                <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded bg-light" action="home.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-floating">
                        <label for="inputEmail">Usuário</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" id="inputEmail" placeholder="e-mail">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-floating">
                        <label for="inputPassword">Senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Senha">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="w-100 mt-4 btn btn-lg btn-success">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="reset" class="w-100 mt-2 btn btn-lg btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                       
                </form>
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Código da Pagina 2

```
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tela de Boas Vindas</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="font-size: 50px; font-family: arial light; position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color: black; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <h6>Login bem sucedido</h6>
    </div>
    <p style="font-size: 40px; font-family: arial light; position: absolute; 
    left: 50%;  top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color: black; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <b> SEJA BEM VINDO (A), </b>
    <div style="font-size: 50px; font-family: arial light; position: relative; 
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 25%; text-align: center; ">
        <?php echo $_POST['usuario'] ?>!
    </div>

    </p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vê se te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693758/passing-form-data-to-another-html-page#answer-62967010

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se pode ajudar, mas vc poderia colocar um link no primeiro arquivo que direciona-se para o segundo arquivo.